# C++ unmanaged code inside winform

Tags: c#, c++, winforms, directx

First: I am using C# and C++ on windows 7.

I have created a basic rendering engine in c++ with directx 10. It works good as a stand alone application. But, when I sending the Form.Handle of a WinForm I want to render inside to the engine it crashes during D3D10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain with the following error:

```
HRESULT: 0x887a0001 (2289696769)
Name: DXGI_ERROR_INVALID_CALL
```

I get the handle from the winform during loading of the form.

```
unsafe {
  void *ptr=m_view.Handle.ToPointer();
  uint v = (uint)ptr;
  lhandle = v.ToString();
};
```

Question also asked on gamedev.stackexchanged, was recommended asking it here as well.

Comment: `Control.Handle` (a Form is a Control) is an IntPtr. If you want to convert it to a string, just call its ToString method.

Comment: Yes, I did that originally. Same error tho.

Comment: If you're running in 64-bit, that's going to fail because a pointer is 64 bits and a `uint` is only 32 bits.

Comment: I'm doing these as well: Handle.ToInt32(), Handle.ToInt64() and Handle.ToString(). They all give me the same value.

Comment: They will be the same value because even on x64 HWND values are constrained to fit a 32-bit integer. I can't find proof of that though I'm fairly certain it was Raymond Chen who blogged that fact.

Comment: If I were you, I'd get XNA and dig into its source code to see how they combined WinForms and Direct3D. Or just use XNA..

Answer (score 0):

One has to create a **CHILD** to the parent window, not use the parent window handle directly.